# using Union types in GraphQL typedDefs

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am typing out my `typedDefs` and for one property it can return either `String` or `Boolean`.

```
const typeDefs = `
    type Analysis {
    id: String
    analysisName: String
    creator: String
    description: String
    datesValid: String 
}
`
```

I want `datesValid` to be either `String` or `Boolean`. I tried:

```
const typeDefs = `
    ...
    datesValid: boolString 
}

union boolString = String | Boolean
`
```

But this resulted in a `500` internal server error when trying to query via GraphiQL.

My end goal here is to type it as either `String | Boolean`

Answer (score 0):

According to the GraphQL specification type unions can only be [created from object types](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/October2016/#sec-Unions). This means what you want to do is not possible.

I am sure there is a different way of solving you issue. Maybe a nullable date type is solving you problem? Or an enum that could have multiple values (e.g. `VALID`, `INVALID`, `PENDING`)? In extreme cases you own scalar type could serve the purpose.

Usually these limitations in the specifications are also meant to help people build consistent and simple to use APIs.